# Specifying a Delegate before ViewDidLoad in Tabs

Tags: ios, delegates, uitabcontroller

So, I followed this tutorial: http://enroyed.com/ios/how-to-pass-data-between-ios-tab-bars-using-delegate/

And the most important part of the tutorial:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
   SecondViewController *svc = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
svc.delegate = self; //important !! otherwise delegation will not work !
}
```

The problem is that even if I put it in "viewWillLoad", it still forces me to click on my tab before it initializes.  How can I specify this before I click on the tab?

**Edit**

I have a three tab project.  I used that tutorial in the link pass data from tab 1 to tab 2.  The data passed is a url from a webview on tab 1 to a url on tab 2.  The url gets pass when I click a link on the 1st tab.

The data does get passed, but only if I physically click on the 2nd tab first and then click back to the 1st and click on the link.

So, it appears to me that my code above only runs if I physically click on the 2nd tab.

Comment: Before what initializes? What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that - until you actually go to tab item 2, `secondViewController` is not fully initialised, and so there is no data to transfer from vc2 to vc1. In particular, `secondViewController`'s view has not yet loaded, so there is no value to be had from it's slider yet, and no slider, so also no IBAction method to call to trigger the delegate method. Indeed, as the data transfer is only triggered on moving the slider in VC2, it should be fairly obvious that until you *go* to vc2 *and move the slider*, nothing is going to happen.

The example you link to uses the delegation pattern, which seems a fairly poor way to deal with your problem. The delegation pattern most comfortably fits with the scenario where there is a hierarchical relationship between delegator (owned) and delegatee (owner) ... not always, but most commonly. In a tab bar controller, the relationships are more like kindred child relationships to the tab bar controller itself.

You haven't offered enough detail in your question as to what you want to achieve, but you need to consider this:

When a tabBarController loads, all of it's child viewControllers are *initialised* but their views are not *loaded*.

This means that these methods do get called:

```
//if loading from a xib or in code
- (id) initWithNibName:bundle

//if loading from a storyboard
- (id) initWithCoder:
- (void) awakeFromNib
```

But the view loading methods (`viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` etc) do not get called as the view does not get loaded unless you actually open the relevant tab.

You could solve this by putting an initialised variable into your viewController2 (in one of the `init` methods) and accessing that variable via property syntax from vc1. But then, you might as well just put an initialised value directly into vc1. You need to think closely about how each vc is dependent on the other, how you can decouple that dependency, and perhaps how to set up an independent data source that both vcs can access as needed. This could be a model class, or `NSUserDefault`s, or a property in your `appDelegate`... just a few of the many possible solutions.

Comment: Wow, this helps. Now just need an example of how to get this done.  I'll get it figured out.

Comment: Ok, so I added this to my 1st tab.  ClientViewController *vc2 = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    self.delegate = vc2; -------Same issue.  Also, I put it into "awakeFromNib, because I'm using Storyboard.  Same issue.  Not sure how to use initWithCoder.

Comment: @tjberte Forget delegates for now, you don't need them, they are just going to confuse you. You  already have the references to each viewController via the `tabBarController.viewControllers` array. Your question isn't clear enough to help much further. I suggest you work with the advice you have been given here, then if/when you get stuck edit this question describing exactly what you are trying to do, what data you are hoping to pass, and where you get stuck. Don't refer to that tutorial though, just describe _your_ task and _your_ (nonworking) solution, showing _your_ code.

Comment: Thans for your patience "He Was".  Please refer to my edit again.  I have a tabControllerBar.  It has three tabs.  The first two have web views.  What I want is, is that when I click a link on tab one, it opens that link the webview on tab 2.  It's that simple, and I've spent two days on the issue now.  First was trying to figure out how to pass the data, which that tutorial answered, and now this issue.